# Horizontal scrollview listing multiple image side by side

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I am using horizontal scroll view to list images . But what is happening is multiple images are showing side by side. what I want is to show one image taking full screen width and on scroll show next image
my code is as follows

**page4.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter">
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**page4.java**:

```
package com.example.namrathasrinivas.karnatakatemples;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * Created by namrathasrinivas on 23/07/15.
 */
public class page4 extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page4);

        int[] drawables = {R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,R.drawable.img5,R.drawable.img6};

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setId(i);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getResources(), drawables[i]));

            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            layout.addView(imageView);
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

add LinearLayout property

```
android:baselineAligned="true"
```

Comment: but i want horizontal scroll view

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you used RecyclerView or Viewpager

[Articles Collection for RecyclerView](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/category/recyclerview/)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want image to be placed in Horizontal scroll view instead of ViewPagers then set the minimum_width property to your ImageView like below

```
imageView.setMinimumWidth(getScreenWidth());

  private int getScreenWidth() {

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    return size.x;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of horizontal scroll view you can use recyclerview as horizontal view is easy for use.
Implementation is like:

```
mRecyclerViewImages.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,true));
```

Set below view to adapter (take singal image view like):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@color/cpb_white"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_image_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_image_size"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#DBDBDB"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/camera" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```